# Which temp directory should I use in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm developing a tomcat webapp. When run, my webapp generates data files that I'd like to be persistent between tomcat restarts, or at least I'd like to control when they're deleted. Both [workDir](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html) (i.e., `javax.servlet.context.tempdir`) and the java temp dir (i.e. `java.io.tmpdir`) are implied to be temporary. Is there some other directory I could use?

Comment: This is a closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853387/clarifications-on-tomcats-temp-and-work-directories

Answer (score 3):

You can use any directory you want. Just make sure that it is writable by the user running the Tomcat process. If you want to have control over when it is cleaned, then it is not strictly speaking a "temp" directory, it is just a directory.