# what is this path 'tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp' in tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

My customer told what is path of

```
'tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp'
```

but i don`t know well what is it.
I saw these folder fist time. and maybe the path is created just in operation environment that in my environment of development, these path isn't created.
what is that path and is that must necessity on tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

work directory is where your compiled `JSPs` and other static resources will go.

if you have Deployed archive file as `ROOT.war` folder with name `_` will be created in `tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/` otherwise the folder name will be same as that of your web archieve file.

Note: It is advised to clear work directory before every deployment.

[Clarifications on Tomcat's "temp" and "work" directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8853387/3734640)

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html

Comment: i just had .java sources without jsp source in my project. i don't know why this path be created and i didn't use jsp never. so these path is must have a necessary in my project?

Comment: Even if you don't have `JSP` files, these folders will be created implicitly. Please post the directory structure and what exactly you want to do so that I can help you out

Comment: i didn't know these folder will be create implicitly. thanks for your help